# How to include 'NULL' value in Microsoft SQL server Report Builder

Tags: sql, reportbuilder

I would like to include NULL value from the database in Micorsoft SQL Server Report Builder 2012.

Problem:

Whenever I try to include NULL value in parameter drop-down list.. I can't sort by 'NULL' values in my report.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the Null values go last? 
Well I had problems when I tried to order my results by Query or by hand (I mean, like selecting how to order in the tablix) because none of this would work at all.

It will result for sure if you use "Dynamic Order". :)

It's not too "Comfortable" to use it because when you run the report you will have to click in the column you will use as a reference to order your report and when it's done you will be able to sabe or print your report.

It would be great if it ordered the results by itself by just running the report but it won't work.

:) I hope I could help.